# Most recent transform in tf Tree

Tags: ros, transforms, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to ask that why the value of Most recent transform in my transformation tree so high? Does it mean that there is too much latency in generating the transformations? My tf tree:
[image: image description]

Thanks in advance.
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208510/most-recent-transform-in-tf-tree/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, those values are actually stamps in [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so "*time in seconds since Thursday, 1 January 1970*". You can convert those timestamps pretty easily ([this](http://www.epochconverter.com/) site can do it).

For instance, for `map -> odom_combined`, the last transform is dated `2015-05-01T18:29:40+00:00` ([link](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1430504980.224)).

The time 'between' two transforms (if that even makes sense) would be calculated by subtracting their respective timestamps.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4